# Avoid app logging to syslog

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to setup logging for an app with a new custom conf file under `/etc/rsyslog.d`
as below & name the file as 30-custom.conf

```
$template DailyPerHostLogs, "/var/log/rsyslog/<new_folder>/%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%-%HOSTNAME%.log
app* -?DailyPerHostLogs
& stop
```

I did restarted `rsyslog`.. after above change but some how whatever logging is being written to`%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%-%HOSTNAME%.log` file under `/var/log/rsyslog/<new_folder> /` is also being written to `/var/log/syslog`.

Is there a way I can avoid it ..not to write to default `/var/log/syslog`? 
Did i miss any step here?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5

Comment: read `man syslog.conf`, and look at `/etc/syslog.conf`. What Facility and Priority are you using in your logging calls?

Comment: Sorry for delay response. I didn't changed anything in /etc/syslog.conf. Do we need to change anything there ?  what i am trying to achieve is execute my custom.conf before it executes the default.conf file , thought it happens custom.conf logging comes to syslog which i don't want.

Comment: I repeat, "What Facility and Priority are you using in your logging calls?" The Facility and Priority govern how the `syslog` rules handle the request.

Comment: I assume you are asking below info ..correct me if i am wrong as i am newbie 
`auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log`
`*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog`
`#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log`
`#daemon.*                       -/var/log/daemon.log`
`kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log`
`#lpr.*                          -/var/log/lpr.log`
`mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log`
`#user.*                         -/var/log/user.log`
`mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err`

Comment: No, I'm asking how your app specifies the Facility and Priority. Show us the "put a message into syslog" call that your app uses.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think, your 50-default.conf file is read before this file, which causes your logs to be written in the syslog file.

Specify this in the 50-default.conf file, before the line,

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          /var/log/syslog
```

That should work.